# Django 1.4.2 / South 0.7.6 database error - DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS

Tags: django, django-south

When I run `python manage.py runserver` I get the following error:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <bound method Command.inner_run of <django.contrib.staticfiles.management.commands.runserver.Command object at 0x1cc9cd0>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 91, in inner_run
    self.validate(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 266, in validate
    num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/validation.py", line 30, in get_validation_errors
    for (app_name, error) in get_app_errors().items():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 158, in get_app_errors
    self._populate()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 64, in _populate
    self.load_app(app_name, True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 88, in load_app
    models = import_module('.models', app_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/South-0.7.6-py2.7.egg/south/models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from south.db import DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/South-0.7.6-py2.7.egg/south/db/__init__.py", line 81, in <module>
    db = dbs[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS]
KeyError: 'default'
```

Here is my **settings.py**:

```
 DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'foureggs',
        'USER': 'myuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'mypass',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

Here is a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10058035/south-django-1-4-database-error) with the same problem. The answer says that "there should be a database named 'default' in your settings". I'm not really following that. My db name is "foureggs" so I want to use that, obviously.

**UPDATE:** When I do `python manage.py diffsettings` I get the following output, which **doesn't look correct** (pasting only the relevant DATABASE line, the rest of the settings look OK):

```
DATABASES = {'default': {'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.dummy', 'TEST_MIRROR': None, 'NAME': '', 'TEST_CHARSET': None, 'TIME_ZONE': 'UTC', 'TEST_COLLATION': None, 'PORT': '', 'HOST': '', 'USER': '', 'TEST_NAME': None, 'PASSWORD': '', 'OPTIONS': {}}}
```

I have only one settings file in my project and it's in the app directory, which is correct. Where does the above DATABASE line come from?

**UPDATE 2: I figured out what's the problem**. It's these 2 extra lines I put to `settings.py` as instructed by [Heroku deployment guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django#database-settings). When I comment them out, everything works fine. Now I need to figure out why it's causing the problem.

```
# Parse database configuration from $DATABASE_URL
import dj_database_url
DATABASES['default'] =  dj_database_url.config()
```

Comment: which version of Django are you using? (python -c "import django; print django.VERSION")

Comment: @furins I'm using Django 1.4.2

Comment: if you remove south from your installed apps does the runserver command fail? (or: has it worked before/have you called a syncdb?)

Comment: @furins It runs fine if I comment out south in the installed apps.

Comment: ps. in the question you mentioned when they suggest a database named "default" they meant the name of the dictionary key, not of the db. your settings are ok, no need to rename anything :)

Comment: ok, just for testing purposes, can you try to run the command "python ./manage.py syncdb" and see if any error/change in the db will be reported?

Comment: @furins Yes, it gives me this error: http://dpaste.com/893587/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is apparently not related to South, but to the DB backend.

1. you may start from here: ["settings.DATABASES is improperly configured" error performing syncdb with django 1.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10228618/settings-databases-is-improperly-configured-error-performing-syncdb-with-djang) and related questions
2. If the aforementioned answers not work, first of all check if psycopg2 library is installed and in your sys.path: if not please install it [Psycopg2 library install instructions here](http://initd.org/psycopg/install/).
3. then you can eventually change your ENGINE setting to: 'postgresql_psycopg2'; in this way you can bypass the built-in engine if for any reason it will not work.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by setting the Heroku config like this instead:

```
# Parse database configuration from $DATABASE_URL
import dj_database_url

dbconfig = dj_database_url.config()
if dbconfig:
    DATABASES['default'] =  dbconfig

# Honor the 'X-Forwarded-Proto' header for request.is_secure()
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'foureggs',
        'USER': 'myuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'mypass',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

You need to fill in the `HOST` and the `PORT` otherwise django doesn't know where your database server is. Only if you are using sqlite can those be empty.

For postgreql, the default port is `5432`. If you are running the server on the same machine, use `'localhost'` for the `'HOST'` key, otherwise put in the IP address of your database server.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, i was working on development environment (MY LAPTOP) where these were my dev settings when i got the error

```
import dj_database_url
DATABASES['default'] =  dj_database_url.config()

if not os.environ.has_key('DATABASE_URL'):
     os.environ['DATABASE_URL'] = 'postgres://my_db:my_db@localhost/my_db'
```

Later on I changed it to this and things started working fine

```
if not os.environ.has_key('DATABASE_URL'):
         os.environ['DATABASE_URL'] = 'postgres://my_db:my_db@localhost/my_db'

import dj_database_url
    DATABASES['default'] =  dj_database_url.config()
```

dj_database_url.config() function call needs DATABASE_URL to be initialized

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem after following the Heroku instructions. You are correct that these lines are the culprit:

```
# Parse database configuration from $DATABASE_URL
import dj_database_url
DATABASES['default'] =  dj_database_url.config()
```

This switches the DATABASES values back to the defaults used by the dj_database_url package, which has the engine "django.db.backends.dummy", etc. If you swap this in for those lines, it should work:

```
# Parse database configuration from $DATABASE_URL
import dj_database_url
DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.config(default='postgres://localhost/foureggs')
```

HOWEVER, you don't want to deploy this to Heroku, as it won't work there. The fix I found assumes that you're using virtual environments. If so, navigate to the folder of your virtual env and into the bin directory (cd $VIRTUAL_ENV/bin), add a file called "postactivate" and save this line in it:

`export DATABASE_URL='postgres://localhost/foureggs'`

Now every time you activate the virtual environment, it will start with that value.